# Need >=GTK 3.16 in my application. How to distribute?

Tags: c++, linux, gtk

I am in need of GTK 3.16 for my application (for the GL Area and the FlowBox). I want to distribute my Program on several Linux distrubtions, such as Debian, Ubuntu, etc. The Problem is that some of them use too old libraries. How can I still distribute? Is there a binary package for Linux of the libs that I can add to my programs package using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Could the person that close-voted at least leave a comment? Why is it too broad? What else can be added? This states the problem I have exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Binary distro-independent app distribution is unfortunately not a solved problem yet, not in a way that would be easy for the developer and safe for the user. That said solutions are improving fast and may be here quite soon. Personal  favorite is [Flatpak](http://flatpak.org/) but it's not at "Just click a link" stage yet. Other alternatives include Ubuntus [Snappy](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy) and [AppImage](http://appimage.org/).

If you want something that's easy for the user right now, AppImage is probably your choice. For the future, I think Flatpak has features (like runtimes and proper sandboxing) that will make it more appealing.